# Using tuple in a numpy shape argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

First post :) Don't shoot me if I do something wrong!

Is there a more shorthand way to define the shape in the below? It works, but is a bit long winded and not dynamic.

```
def neural_net_image_input(image_shape):
    """
    Return a Tensor for a batch of image input
    : image_shape: Shape of the images (taken from CIFAR10)
    : return: Tensor for image input.
    """
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_shape[0], image_shape[1],  image_shape[2]], name='x')
    return x
```

I have searched for around an hour without success, on SO and other sites. I did try this initially,

```
shape = [None, image_shape]
```

but got error (which I do understand)

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

So is there a way to change a tuple into a form that would be accepted in my shape argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tuple addition:

```
shape=(None,)+image_shape
# or if you want to allow lists and other sequences for image_shape:
shape=(None,)+tuple(image_shape)
```

or on recent Python versions with iterable unpacking generalizations:

```
shape=(None, *image_shape)
```

Comment: That unpacking generalization is a new one to me.  I can think of some indexing cases where it would useful, replacing a conventional `I,J = ...` unpacking.  `x[ (None, *(...)) ]`.